# How to Add Nginx Module ngx_http_secure_link_module on Debian 10

Tags: nginx

I installed LEMP on Debian 10 using the tutorial that is [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mariadb-php-lemp-stack-on-debian-10). I using nginx/1.14.2.

I want to add the Nginx Module `ngx_http_secure_link_module` to protect the download link.

I have searched for the tutorial on Google, but it's very rare to discuss Nginx Module, especially `ngx_http_secure_link_module`.

I'm a beginner Nginx, I have tried several tutorials on YouTube and Google search but the module is not installed properly. I really hope to get a tutorial on adding the nginx module `ngx_http_secure_link_module` here.

I would really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the package `nginx-extras` to get the secure link module. Once installed, restart nginx.

```
sudo apt install nginx-extras
```

Comment: This adds a lot of modules that I don't need, is there a way to just add the nginx_secure module?

Comment: @RenomuReza Nobody said you have to use all the modules!

Comment: ngx http secure link module seems to work well. I mean, does the added module require a lot of storage space?

Comment: @RenomuReza The amount of disk space used is trivial.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the module that I need is working well. Is this the best way to add the nginx module or is there another way? I see this method is very different from what I found in Google and YouTube searches.

Comment: If you want to do it the "Debian" way, then this is it.